# Azure API Management find-and-replace not working for URLs

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am running API-M that calls another system (SAP) to call an OData Service. The OData service will return a response with URL. I don't want to expose the internal URL on API-M but the policies are not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData">
    <edmx:Reference Uri="http://xxxxx.sap-internal.company.cloud/sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_AGGREGATION',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='LOCAL')/$value" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
```

I wanted to mask http://xxxxx.sap-internal.company.cloud to http://xxxxapim.azure-api.net

Basically, I am using both policies. I have also tried using one of both policies individually

```
<outbound>
    <base />
    <find-and-replace from="xxxxx.sap-internal.company.cloud" to="xxxxapim" />
    <redirect-content-urls />
</outbound>
```

In trace, I am seeing the policies.

I am not sure why is it not performing the policy correctly. Anyone else encountered the same thing?

I tried using API-M Policies to do the conversion but it's not working correctly.

Comment: I am having a similar issue in that the CreatedAtRoute 201 creates a "Location" header that points to our backend API which we are trying to hide. The `find-and-replace` policy and the `redirect-content-urls` appears to affect only the body of the response thus ignoring the headers.

Answer (score 0):

The policies which you have used is correct even I have tried. I have an another approach use a custom script policy to replace the internal URL with the masked URL in the OData service response:

```
<outbound>
    <base />
    <set-body template="liquid">
        @{
            var response = context.Response.Body.As<string>();
            var modifiedResponse = response.Replace("http://xxxxx.sap-internal.company.cloud", "http://xxxxapim.azure-api.net");
            return modifiedResponse;
        }
    </set-body>
</outbound>
```

- This `template="liquid"` allows you to use a script inside the `@{}` block. The script retrieves the response body, replaces the internal URL with the masked URL using the `Replace` method, and returns the modified response.

I had a sample API to get register in APIM and tried that which you had given in the above to mask the internal URL returned by an some ex-service in Azure API Management.

[image]

I have redirect by using a function app and tried to mask the internal URL exposed.

```
#r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    // Call the OData service and retrieve the response
    // ...

    // Create a new response message
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    // Modify the response using policies
    response.Headers.Add("New-Header", "Value");

    // Replace the internal URL in the response body with the masked URL
    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    responseBody = responseBody.Replace("http://demo.sap-internal.company.cloud", "http://demoapim.azure-api.net");
    response.Content = new StringContent(responseBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    // Return the modified response
    return response;
}
```

**Output:**

Response of the Replaced URL.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the find-and-replace policy and an SAP OData API. On my end it was caused by an response encoding error. The APIM trace showed "Compression br not supported". When I limited allowed encoding to gzip and deflate only, the expression started to work as expected. Curious if that is your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue in that the **CreatedAtRoute 201** creates a "Location" header that points to our backend API, which we are trying to hide. The `<find-and-replace>` policy and the `<redirect-content-urls>` appear to affect only the *Body* of the response, thus ignoring the headers.

My workaround was to add the following `Outbound` policy to adjust the `Location` header in the Response:

```
<set-header name="Location" exists-action="override">
     <value>@{
               string originalUrl = context.Response.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Location", "");
                string newUrl = originalUrl.Replace("https://privacy-guardian-dev.azurewebsites.net", "https://guardian-api-dev.azure-api.net");
                return newUrl;
                }</value>
 </set-header>
```